# One website showing as text on LAMP

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

I have a local install of Apache / MySQL and PHP on Fedora Linux.

I know PHP is running ok as some of my websites are running fine and if I create a simple  file I can see I am running PHP 5.4.1.

Searching Google brings up tons of hits where the issue is PHP is not running at all but that isn't the case here - it's only one site that displays as plain text instead of processing as php.

I'm sure it's some kind of seeting in httpd.conf but have had a look and there is nothing obvious (to me anyway).

Comment: Perhaps you need to configure httpd.conf - something like this http://library.linode.com/lamp-guides/fedora-15

Comment: It can also be something silly as having an additional space in <? php etc. hard to tell.

Comment: As suggested by JK look for syntax. Also it would be nice to check your setup by phpinfo();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some pages work and some don't check if it's a short_open_tag in php.ini issue. `(it allows for <? instead of only <?php)`

Comment: Thanks - that was it, it was a legacy site that still used short tags.